# Sorting by converted date in a distinct select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In a `SELECT DISTINCT` I'm converting a `datetime` into a `DD/MM/YYYY` format, I then want to order by that same field. Once it's converted the original value becomes inaccessible with this error:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified

Current code looks something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CONVERT(varchar, dateLink.datCreated, 103) AS LastPaymentDate
FROM 
    Person p
INNER JOIN 
    Payment dateLink ON p.paymentID = dateLink.ID
ORDER BY 
    dateLink.datCreated
```

The code above shows the error I've mentioned. I've tried to order by the alias which runs but because it's a varchar it sorts by the day only (I think? Doesn't sort properly either way). Is there another conversion I can do? I need the date to be in a `DD/MM/YYYY` format while it's a `datetime` in the table (`DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm`). The query also needs to be ordered by the date `DESC`.

Comment: You could use a `GROUP BY` instead, but I would ask why you are formatting your value in the SQL layer in the first place; that's a task for the presentation layer.

Comment: That is an extremely good point which didn't cross my mind. Guess I got caught up wanting to make it work this way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can convert the datetime column into date instead of varchar then in presentation layer you can format it as you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CONVERT(date, dateLink.datCreated, 103) AS LastPaymentDate
FROM 
    Person p
INNER JOIN 
    Payment dateLink ON p.paymentID = dateLink.ID
ORDER BY 
    LastPaymentDate
```

Comment: there is no need for that see my answer

Comment: This won't work for what I'm doing. There are other parts of the select which I didn't include in my question that rely on the `DISTINCT` being in the main select. Appreciate the input tho. :)

Comment: @Usiek I proposed another solution.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur this works! Any chance you know if the SQL `date` field can be cast directly to a .net `DateTime`?

Comment: As per I know it should be.